# Simple Login Page

Tags: java, sql, servlets, authentication

I'm trying to make a simple login page for a website which uses MVC I'm attempting create a servlet and JSP for it and I really have no idea what to do.

Can anyone show me a simple example of a login servlet which uses a simple if statement for the login verification as well as creates a new cookie and sends it in the request.

I've currently made a boolean method in the User model which uses an SQL query to get the login information.

I'm assuming that the result of this method needs to be passed into the if statement at which point it assigns the user a cookie, and sends them onto the homepage. Else they are denied access and sent back to the login page with some sort of message explaining the problem.

Here's the method which gets database access and runs the query.

```
public boolean getLoginInfo(){

    try{
        DBAccess dbAccess = new DBAccess();

        String sql = "SELECT username, password FROM owner WHERE username = '" + this.username
                + "'AND password = '" + this.password +"';";

        dbAccess.runUpdateQuery(sql);
        dbAccess.close();

        return true;
    }

    catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: Can I try to log in as username = `"'; DROP TABLE owner;--"` please?

Comment: You can certainly attempt to do authentication and authorization yourself, but why not create (or just configure a provided) LoginModule?  This is what JAAS was created to solve.

Comment: Standard warning: what if the user enters `';DROP TABLE owner;--` ?

Comment: ahh, little Bobby Tables trying to log in again

Comment: @Pleepleus - oh how I wish there was a +10 button!

Comment: Ok, I just want a really basic/simple login page. I'm a complete novice to MVC so just need a basic servlet which does the bare minumum of taking this method and using it in the if statement as verification

Comment: Also yeah I know what you mean about potential threats I'm not that concerned with that level of security / verification at the moment just want to understand the basics

Comment: David points out a major flaw, and another is that you should NEVER store your passwords in clear text.  Even if this is a simple application with mostly meaningless data that nobody would really want access too, the problem is that many user use the same password for all of their accounts.  If your DB is compromised, a hacker would have a list of potential usernames and passwords that they could exploit on any number of sites containing far more sensitive information than you are storing.

Comment: This is for a school project so security isn't of a very high importance.

Comment: If this is for a school project, why have security at all... unless the project is about implementing some form of security layer.  Go above and beyond the requirements.  Show the teacher that you prefer to keep your cookies on a shelf higher than the last one.

Comment: It's because I need to store a cookie for the session and need a basic form of verification so that the session can be tracked etc.

edit: and the login page will allow me to associate a cookie with a user from the start

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend letting your server handle authentication for you.  See [jaas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Authentication_and_Authorization_Service).  This will be more flexible and secure.

Comment: This isn't a website which is actually going to be put online. It's for a school project and will only be ran locally,

Comment: If it's a school project, the goal is to learn.  There's no sense in learning how to do something the wrong way.

Comment: Because I need to learn the basics before I can move onto the advanced parts. I do agree with you though